# How to use custom preload function after insert?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How to use custom model function to preload selected data after `Repo.insert`? I won't duplicate code from model in controller.

In Post Model:

```
def preload_all(query) do
  tags = from(t in Tag, select: %{id: t.id, value: t.id})
  from b in query, preload: [:user, tags: ^tags]
end
```

In Controller:

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, post} ->
    # post = post |> Post.preload_all
    post = Repo.preload(post, [:user, :tags])
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Pass in a query which fetches post with `id` = `post.id`:

   ```
   case Repo.insert(changeset) do
     {:ok, post} ->
       post = Repo.one(Post.preload_all(from p in Post, where: p.id == ^post.id))
   end
   ```

   Note that this will execute one more query than required.
2. Extract the preload parameters to a different function and use it from both the controller and the model:

   ```
   # Post Model
   def preload_args do
     tags = from(t in Tag, select: %{id: t.id, value: t.id})
     [:user, tags: tags]
   end

   def preload_all(query) do
     from b in query, preload: ^preload_args
   end

   # Controller
   case Repo.insert(changeset) do
     {:ok, post} ->
       post = Repo.preload(post, Post.preload_args)
   end
   ```

(All code untested; please point out syntax or other errors if you spot any.)